# Get license error every build in visual studio Janus Controls

Tags: visual-studio, janus, licenses.licx

We've Janus Controls in our solution.

I've updated the Janus controls to a newer version and I get a "Trial" Message when I build the solution in visual studio.

The problem is, I've the license for the controls, but I still get the message, so I have to find my error in the license file.

And here is my problem: I get this "Trial" Message only on the first build. So I have the restart my PC or have the "Repair" the Janus controls to get the error/message a second time.

I already tried to restart visual studio and Clean/Build in every variation,
but nothing worked.

So is there a way, to get my license error on every build?

It's hard to find an error when I have to restart my PC after every build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall Janus and clean its folder then install it again.

Also try to remove the references for Janus Library in your projects then add them again, then clean & rebuild your projects.

Comment: I know what you mean.
But there are different versions of Janus (4.0.47.0, 4.0.36.0, 2.0.30.0) in the license file.
Also there are different unused license entries.
I want the clean this garbage and I need the rebuild the solution a  few times for that. So I need a way to get this "trial" and "not licensed" error message on every build.